# Minor issue related to glmnet and LOOCV in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, regression, linear-regression, cross-validation

I tried to fit a Regularization model (LASSO, Ridge, ElasticNet) using Leave one out cross-validation split with cv.glmnet and glmnet.

I used this [DATASET](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/forest-fires/), the dataset has 517 rows and 13 columns (two of them are categorical variables). The dependent variable is "area".

I would like to build a model without the categorical variables. Then is to calculate the coefficients mean of each LOOCV run, as well as the mean of R-squared and Root mean square.

The last 10 rows of the dataset are the following

```
tail(wdbc,10)
    X Y month day FFMC   DMC    DC  ISI temp RH wind rain  area
508 2 4   aug fri 91.0 166.9 752.6  7.1 25.9 41  3.6  0.0  0.00
509 1 2   aug fri 91.0 166.9 752.6  7.1 25.9 41  3.6  0.0  0.00
510 5 4   aug fri 91.0 166.9 752.6  7.1 21.1 71  7.6  1.4  2.17
511 6 5   aug fri 91.0 166.9 752.6  7.1 18.2 62  5.4  0.0  0.43
512 8 6   aug sun 81.6  56.7 665.6  1.9 27.8 35  2.7  0.0  0.00
513 4 3   aug sun 81.6  56.7 665.6  1.9 27.8 32  2.7  0.0  6.44
514 2 4   aug sun 81.6  56.7 665.6  1.9 21.9 71  5.8  0.0 54.29
515 7 4   aug sun 81.6  56.7 665.6  1.9 21.2 70  6.7  0.0 11.16
516 1 4   aug sat 94.4 146.0 614.7 11.3 25.6 42  4.0  0.0  0.00
517 6 3   nov tue 79.5   3.0 106.7  1.1 11.8 31  4.5  0.0  0.00
```

My attempted code is as follows

```
set.seed(123) 
  data <- read.csv("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/forest-fires/forestfires.csv") 
  data<-data[-(3:4)] 
  nrFolds <- 517
  folds <- rep_len(1:nrFolds, nrow(data))
  for(k in 1:nrFolds) {
      fold <- which(folds == k)
      data.train <- data[-fold,]
      data.test <- data[fold,]
      x.train <- as.matrix(data.train[-11])
      y.train <- as.matrix(data.train[11])
      x.test <- as.matrix(data.test[-11])
      y.test <- as.matrix(data.test[11])
      cv <- cv.glmnet(x.train, y.train, alpha = 0)
      # cv$lambda.min
      model <- glmnet(x.train, y.train, alpha = 0, lambda = cv$lambda.min)
      coef(model) 
      predictions <- model %>% predict(x.test) %>% as.vector()
      RMSE <- RMSE(predictions, data.test$area)
      Rsquare <- R2(predictions, data.test$area)
      LL <- list(cv,model,coef(model),predictions, RMSE,Rsquare)
  }
  LL
```

The code gives me only one prediction value! and R-square has NA value!.
Also, I am not sure if I am right to use Leave one out cross-validation split with cv.glmnet and glmnet or not.

Any idea to help is appreciated.

***Updated***

I tried to use the `caret` package

I first split the dataset using LOOCV because I want every single observation to be in test process. Then I used `train` function to do my initial idea in the question.

My code

```
data <- read.csv("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/forest-fires/forestfires.csv") 
data<-data[-(3:4)] 
lambda <- 10^seq(-3, 3, length = 100)
predictions <- rep(0,nrow(data))
set.seed(123)
for(i in 1:nrow(data)){
  test.data<-data[i,]
  train.data<-data[-i,]
ridge <- train(
  area ~., data = train.data, method = "glmnet",
  trControl = trainControl("loocv", number = 517),
  tuneGrid = expand.grid(alpha = 0, lambda = lambda))
  coefs=coef(ridge$finalModel, ridge$bestTune$lambda)
  predictions[i] <- ridge %>% predict(test.data)
  RMSE = RMSE(predictions, test.data$area)
  Rsquare = R2(predictions, test.data$area)
  LL<-list(RMSE,Rsquare,coefs,predictions) 
}
```

This code also gives me the following error

```
Error in cor(obs, pred, use = ifelse(na.rm, "complete.obs", "everything")) : 
  incompatible dimensions
In addition: Warning message:
In nominalTrainWorkflow(x = x, y = y, wts = weights, info = trainInfo,  :
  There were missing values in resampled performance measures.
```

**More Update**

I also wrote the following code using `caret` package (Ridge for example)

```
set.seed(123)
data <- read.csv("forestfires.csv") 
data<-data[-(3:4)]  
lambda.grid <-10^seq(10,-2, length =100)
alpha.grid<- 0 #Ridge 
control <- trainControl(method="LOOCV")
srchGrd = expand.grid(alpha = alpha.grid, lambda = lambda.grid)
lm_model <- train(area ~ . , data=data, trControl=control,tuneGrid=srchGrd,method = 'glmnet')
lm_model
coef(lm_model$finalModel, lm_model$bestTune$lambda)
```

Am I right now?

Comment: Well, maybe your expectations were wrong, then ;-) Seriously – what do you mean, "does not work as I expected"? Does it throw errors? Does it have low performance? What is it? Also, I would suggest using `caret` package. You really shouldn't have to do your LOOCV by hand.

Comment: @January, many thanks. I edited my problem. I will then look at the caret package.

Comment: @January, see my comment and the question update, please.

Comment: In your updated code, you repeat your mistake from the previous code: every time you run the loop, you replace your LL. This code will not produce any meaningful results. Regarding caret: this is not how one would normally use it. Caret does the LOO (or whatever you choose) internally and returns all possible measures for the goodness of fit for a range of parameters. However, you run it repeatedly in a loop and still try to calculate (incorrectly) the measures on your own. Moreover, you introduce a new error by trying to calculate R2 on a vector of (mostly) zeroes.

Comment: @January, thanks again, and have a look at my new updated code, please.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so now that you have stated it, the problem is quite obvious. Each time you are in the loop, you assign a new value to the LL. LL doesn't hold all results, just the last one. Try

```
LL <- lapply(1:nrFolds, function(k) {
  fold <- which(folds == k)
  data.train <- data[-fold,]
  data.test <- data[fold,]
  x.train <- as.matrix(data.train[-11])
  y.train <- as.matrix(data.train[11])
  x.test <- as.matrix(data.test[-11])
  y.test <- as.matrix(data.test[11])
  cv <- cv.glmnet(x.train, y.train, alpha = 0)
  # cv$lambda.min
  model <- glmnet(x.train, y.train, alpha = 0, lambda = cv$lambda.min)
  coef(model) 
  predictions <- model %>% predict(x.test) %>% as.vector()
  RMSE <- RMSE(predictions, data.test$area)
  Rsquare <- R2(predictions, data.test$area)
  list(CV=cv, model=model, coefs=coef(model), preds=predictions, rmse=RMSE, r2=Rsquare)
})
```

However, please look into the caret package: it automatizes creation of folds and testing. Also, I would calculate the RMSE and R² post hoc.

**EDIT**: Yes, R2 is `NA`. This is because in the above code, leave-one-out CV is attempted. `rep_len` as above returns the same as `1:517`, so `fold` is basically a number between 1 and 517, each `data.train` has 516 column and `data.test` is a vector. Therefore, `predictions` is a vector of length 1 and R2 cannot be calculated.

However, predictions are returned correctly.

```
preds <- sapply(LL, function(x) x$preds)
```

Not that they are very good, but the question was about running glmnet and not how to make the best predictions.

**EDIT 2**: regarding your updated code. Here is what happens: you first initialize the vector `predictions` with 517 zeroes. In the first iteration of your loop, you tell caret to make a 517 LOO on a training set that contains 516 samples. Caret then returns the optimized ridge model (plus a lot of information which you ignore, like for example RMSE for each parameter value tested). Then, you take make predictions on your test set, which is one sample. You enter this one single sample in the `predictions` vector, which now contains 1 prediction and 516 zeroes. And then you are trying to calculate R2 and RMSE between `predictions` (which is a vector of one prediction and 516 zeroes) and the test response (which is a vector of one value). Which, not unexpectedly, fails. Then you store it all in a list called `LL`, which will get overwritten next time the loop is being run.

How I would do it: remove 33% of the data as validation. Use the remaining 66% with caret to train a *single* model (with LOOCV or K-FOLD in caret to optimize the parameters). Inspect the output of caret; make sure you look at the RMSE which caret provides (and R², if you use something else than LOOCV). Then, test the performance of your model on the validation set.

Comment: many thanks for your answer. I tried the code but R-squared always NA.
It also does not store the prediction together.  In addition, my idea was to calculate the coefficient mean for each explanatory variable as well as the mean of R-squared and RMSE.

Comment: It works for me. Of course R2 is NA, because you are doing LOOCV here (each fold consists of only one  sample to test and (n-1) samples for training), so R2 cannot be anything else. Prediction is present (it is a single number!)